# Passing Variable in url - Karate

Tags: karate

I tried below feature to pass url with variable, but its failing. Please give suggestion. Or we cant try such URL? I demoBaseURL i have given in Karate-config.

```
Background:
```

* url demoBaseUrl

```
Scenario Outline: Check Request and Response 

Given url 'http://abc/web/juk/nmr/Accounts('<accountNumber>')'
    When method GET
    Then status 200
    And match $ == read('AccountResponse.json')
    And print 'response: ', response
```

Examples:
        | accountNumber             | 
        |  PPB00001694              |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the docs on `path` carefully. Try the below change:

```
Scenario Outline: Check Request and Response 

Given path '<accountNumber>'
When method GET
Then status 200
And match $ == read('AccountResponse.json')
And print 'response: ', response
```

Comment: I had tried this option before, but the url is passing as "http://abc/web/juk/nmr/Accounts/accountNumber", but i want the url in the form "'http://abc/web/juk/nmr/Accounts('accountNumber')". So i tried the form which i sent. Please let me know what i have to do if i need the URL in the form "'http://abc/web/juk/nmr/Accounts('accountNumber')".

Comment: @ManjulaM please try forming the URL by string concatenation. ask a friend who knows JavaScript for help. refer this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/540#issuecomment-424704807